# Too many pattern matches to write down for Quadtrees?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, quadtree

Imagine a **quadtree** defined as follow:

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

bad1 = Q u u u u where u = C 255
bad2 = Q (C 0) (C 255) (Q u u u u) (C 64) where u = C 255
```

The constructor allows you to create not well-formed quadtrees. `bad1` should be simply C 255 and `bad2` is not valid too because its bottom-right quadtree (for the same reason, it should be `Q (C 0) (C 255) (C 244) (C 64)`.

So far so good. Checking its well-formness is simply a matter of checking its inner quadtrees recursively. The **base case** is when all inner quadtrees are **leafs**, whereby all colors shouldn't be all equals.

```
wellformed :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
wellformed (Q (C c1) (C c2) (C c3) (C c4)) = any (/= c1) [c2, c3, c4]
wellformed (Q (C c1) (C c2) se (C c4))     = valid se
-- continue defining patters to match e.g Q C C C, C Q Q C, and so on...
```

**Question**: *Can I avoid typing all matches for all possible combination of leafs and quadtrees?*

Please be patient if my question is quite odd, but it's my second-day-Haskell-seamless-learing!

Comment: Depending on what you're interested in, you could just make a `unify` function that detects the "bad" case where all four elements are equal and turns them into a single element.

Comment: @Dan: sure I already did it. I called "sanitize" and does exactly the same as you stated :P

Comment: You could also hide the `Q` constructor from outside the module, and use smart constructors to make sure everything is well-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind...

```
wellformed :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
wellformed (C _) = True
wellformed (Q (C c1) (C c2) (C c3) (C c4)) = any (/= c1) [c2, c3, c4]
wellformed (Q nw ne se sw) = wellformed nw && wellformed ne
   && wellformed se && wellformed sw
```

**EDIT**: or even better:

```
wellformed :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
wellformed (C _) = True
wellformed (Q (C c1) (C c2) (C c3) (C c4)) = any (/= c1) [c2, c3, c4]
wellformed (Q nw ne se sw) = all wellformed [nw, ne, se, sw]
```

**EDIT**: note that the bindings are **wrong**, should be: NW NE SW SE!!!

Comment: `all wellformed [nw ne se sw]` would be shorter and more intuitive :-)

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: Thanks, much more elegant!

Comment: I actually forgot to put `,` between list elements. :-/