# Algorithm to check quadtree horizontal symmetry?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, quadtree

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

> Giving the definition as above, write a predicate to check if a given image (coded as a quadtree) is symmetric in respect of vertical axis (horizontal symmetric). Use anonymous function where possible.

**Question**: *How would you implement horizontal symmetry check for a given quadtree?*

Well, I was thinking at something like this: when a quadtree is just a **leaf**, in that case we have horizontal symmetry. Base case is when quadtree has just **one level** (four leafs) symmetry is just a matter of checking the colors `(c1 == c2 && c3 == c4)`.

**In any other case**, I might check if this condition is recursive satisfied:  `nw equals (fliphorizontal(ne)) && sw equals (fliphorizontal(se))`, where `fliphorizontal` flips the quadtree horizontally and `equals` checks if two quadtrees are equal. However I would like to avoid the use of external function as possible, just anonymous ones if possible.

```
ishsymmetric :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
ishsymmetric (C _)                           = True
ishsymmetric (Q (C c1) (C c2) (C c3) (C c4)) = c1 == c2 && c3 == c4
ishsymmetric (Q nw ne sw se)                 =
```

**EDIT**: fliph example:

```
fliph :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> QT a
fliph (C a)           = C a
fliph (Q nw ne sw se) = Q (fliph ne) (fliph nw) (fliph se) (fliph sw)
```

**EDIT**: final one-function solution (using generalized fold function for quadtrees):

```
ishsymmetric :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
ishsymmetric (C _)       = True
ishsymmetric (Q a b c d) = and $ zipWith equals [a,c] [fliph b,fliph d]
    where
        fold f g (C c)       = g c
        fold f g (Q a b c d) = f (fold f g a) (fold f g b)
                                 (fold f g c) (fold f g d)
        fliph q = fold (\a b c d -> Q b a d c) (\c -> C c) q
        equals (C c1) (C c2)           = c1 == c2
        equals (Q a b c d) (Q e f g h) = and $ zipWith equals [a,b,c,d] [e,f,g,h]
```

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: fixed, thanks.

Comment: edited the first post...

Comment: You can collect and report your improvements as comments, and then edit the question later, so that it includes the comments. If you edit the question 8 times, it's made Community Wiki. CW doesn't generate the rep. So don't edit your posts often.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `where` syntax would suit your needs :-) http://freebsd.pastebin.com/QX1Bi0sj

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: good starting point, thanks.

Comment: @Gremo why do you say "I would like to avoid the use of external function as possible, just anonymous ones."? Any 'external' functions could be inlined as anonymous functions, but that would make it a lot uglier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
ishsymmetric :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> Bool
ishsymmetric (C _)                           = True
ishsymmetric (Q (C c1) (C c2) (C c3) (C c4)) = c1 == c2 && c3 == c4
ishsymmetric (Q nw ne sw se) = equals nw (fliph ne) && equals sw (fliph se)
    where equals (C a) (C b) = a == b
          equals (Q a b c d) (Q e f g h) = equals a e && equals b f && equals c g && equals d h
          fliph (C a)           = C a
          fliph (Q nw ne sw se) = Q (fliph ne) (fliph nw) (fliph se) (fliph sw)
```

But syntactic optimizations are possible. :-/

Comment: Or, alternatively: `equals (Q a b c d) (Q e f g h) = and$zipWith equals [a,b,c,d] [e,f,g,h]` (http://freebsd.pastebin.com/DgMW4Txh).

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: is `and$` the same thing as doing: `foldr (&&) True (zipWith equals [a, b, c, d] [e, f, g, h])`?

Comment: @Gremo: Yep. You can check function signatures by using `:t all` and `:t foldr (&&) True` in GHCi. They are identical. Moreover, you could use `foldl1`, which is a variant of `foldl` that has no starting value argument. BTW, I've already pointed out to `all` in your previous question "[Too many pattern matches to write down for Quadtrees?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4894798/298282)". :-) Wait, `$` is an application operator, defined in `Prelude`, see [Application operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-36-).

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: i like the zipWith solution, is quite concise and elegant. I assume that `and` is not short-circuit like `&&`, right?

Comment: @Gremo: Well, `zipWith` allows you any morphism you'd like (ensured, that the result is a list), while `and` is a shorthand for `foldl1 (&&)`, which produces a list of `Bool` values. Dammit, why am I confusing `all` and `and`? :-)

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: that is, yes is short circuit :). Answer accepted, thanks again for your helpful contribute.

Comment: @Gremo: I'm happy to have been useful. Take +1 from me, too, for learing FP  :^)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ishsymmetric qt = qt == fliph qt
```

Comment: Do you mean `ishsymmetric qt = equals qt (fliph qt)`?

Comment: @Gremo I'm fairly sure that the `equals` method is rendered unnecessary...since `QT` derives `Eq` already.